# python store new value

Tags: python, csv, pandas

hi im newbi in python programming and im still learning it.
i want to ask i have a csv data wich have 5 columns(TC,TD,TG,P,CTTR). and i want to store new value for CTTR column.

the new formula to CTTR column is

[image]

i is the line's number.

but i do not know how to write the formula to python.
i know how to get the original CTTR value as input with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.read_csv("output1.csv")

cttr = data_df['CTTR']

print cttr
```

i have 12 number of lines and i would like the output have same number of lines as the input. if index [0] , the value of cttr[i-2] and cttr[i-1]  will be ==0 and when index [11], the value of cttr[i+2] and cttrs[i+1] will be ==0. and then  i would like replace the original value of  CTTR with the New value of CTTR to csv.

The original CTTR value

```
0
2
2
23
18
28
27
58
41
12
35
20
```

the output i expected

```
0.6------> (0 + 2*0 + 4*0 + 2*2 + 2)/10 
3.5 -----> (0 + 2*0 +4*2 +2*2 + 23)/10
7.6
16.2
20.3
28.3
33.9
40.8
36.6
27.8
24.5-----> (41 + 2*12 + 4*35 + 2*20 + 0)/10
16.2-----> (12 + 2*35 + 4*20 +2*0 + 0)/10
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not exactly clear on the output you're looking for, but one way you could do it is:

```
vals = df.CTTR.values

np.array([vals[i-2] + 2*vals[i-1] + 4*vals[i] + 2*vals[i+1] + vals[i+2] for i in range(2,len(vals)-2)])/10.
```

That said, basically you're implementing a weighted rolling average for which I'm sure there is an implementation already (maybe have a look around pandas [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html))

If you want to have zeros in the first/last to positions where no observations are available, you can do:

```
np.append(np.append([0,0],np.array([vals[i-2] + 2*vals[i-1] + 4*vals[i] + 2*vals[i+1] + vals[i+2] for i in range(2,len(vals)-2)])/10.),[0,0])
```

Although this is getting a bit unwieldy, so you might want to wrap this in a function like so:

```
def calc_new_cttr(series):
    vals = series.values
    cttrs = np.array([vals[i-2] + 2*vals[i-1] + 4*vals[i] + 2*vals[i+1] + vals[i+2] for i in range(2,len(vals)-2)])/10.
    return np.append(np.append([0,0], cttrs),[0,0])
```

Which you can then call directly on your series like this:

```
calc_new_cttr(data_df["CTTR"])
```

To write to csv, you can assign the transformed column to your dataframe and export to csv using pandas csv writer:

```
data_df["transformed_cttr"] = calc_new_cttr(data_df["CTTR"])
data_df.to_csv("/path/to/your/file.csv")
```

------------EDIT-------------

The boundary behavior described in your latest comment can be achieved by simply padding out the series before applying the transformation and then returning the resulting array without the first and last two entries:

```
def cttr(series):
    vals = np.append(np.append([0,0], series.values),[0,0])
    cttrs = np.array([vals[i-2] + 2*vals[i-1] + 4*vals[i] + 2*vals[i+1] + vals[i+2] for i in range(2,len(vals)-2)])/10.
    return cttrs
```

Comment: hey thank you for answering. sory, but i have 12 number of lines and i would like the output have same number of lines as the input. if index [0] , the value of vals[i-2] and vals[i-1]  will be ==0 and when index [11], the value of vals[i+2] and vals[i+1] will be ==0. and i would like replace the original value of  CTTR with the New value of CTTR to csv.

Comment: Not sure I understand this - what is a line for you? Are you talking about behavior of the filter at the boundaries (i.e. where `i-2` and `i-1` don't exist)?

Comment: sory for my bad english. i mean I have total amounted to 12 pieces of data input (0 2 2 23 18 28 27 58 41 12 35 20) but your code just give me 8 pieces of data output. and yes when the i-2 and i-1 don't exist I want to give a value of 0 by default.

Comment: im sory my explanation really bad, but what i want is not set default of the transformed_cttr as 0 but set default of [vals[i-2][vals[i-1[vals[i+2]and[vals[i+1] as 0 when the array does not exist. for example when i=0, it wil [0 + 2*0 + 4*2 + 2*2+ 23)/10 = 3.5. i update the output which is i expected.

Comment: I've edited the answer again, please do accept it if it answers your question now or clarify if anything else is not working.

Comment: i still did not get [ 0, 3.5] and [24.5, 8], ( the first two and the last two). the current code you give me generate same output with the last one. i still expected to generate output 0, 3.5, 24.5, 8 not only 7.6 ,16.2 ,20.3 ,28.3 ,33.9,40.8,36.6,27.8 so it will same amount with input.

Comment: sorry, shouldn't have popped off start and end - fixed above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128469/discussion-between-kim-hyesung-and-nils-gudat).